# How to subset columns with dplyr select dependent upon values in columns in a one row dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a single row dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(who = "Tom", who2 = "Tom", who3 = "Harry", how_many = 48, 
                 reserve = "Mary"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                 ), row.names = c(NA, -1L))

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  who   who2  who3  how_many reserve
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  
1 Tom   Tom   Harry       48 Mary
```

I'd like to subset columns by condition, but I get the error:
`Error: condition must be a logical, not list` from the code below.

```
df %>% 
 if_else(who == who2, select(who3), select(how_many, reserve))
```

I think I understand why I'm getting the error - this code would not be valid if there was more than 1 row, but can't think of another way how to do this in a chain of `dplyr` piped functions.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What is the desired result?

Comment: the result would be just to have one column `who3` if the condition is met, or (else) 2 columns `how_many` & `reserve`.

Comment: If your output is going to have different columns, you're better off using a standard `if` statement of some sort. You can't use vectorize functions like `if_else` to returns objects of different shapes (nor can you pipe data into `if_else`, it's meant to be used inside a `mutate()` or `summarize()`). This really isn't a pipe friendly operation. What's the next step in the pipe?

Comment: thanks - it's actually the last step in the pipe. Based upon the results higher up I want to reduce the columns down to the ones that matter. The actual values in the columns denote what's of importance, hence the need for something like if_else logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way it to pipe the data into an expression block and then run more standard code to conditionally select what columns you want.

```
df %>% {if (pull(., who )==pull(., who2 )) {
  select(., who3)
} else {
  select(., how_many, reserve)
}}
```

Comment: that worked - thank you. Might be a silly question but what syntactic purpose does the `.` serve after the select opening bracket?

Comment: You need to pass in the original data set that was passed to the `{}` block. It's not just going to pass though the if statement. The `select()` function needs a data.frame/tibble as it's first parameter.